# How to extract values from a nested json that has a mutable key in pyspark 2.47 while maintaining the position of the row?

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

THere is this DF were one of the columns is a nested JSON that has crucial info.
The primary key always changes and any row can have 0 to 10 different primary keys.
Keys 1, 2 and 3 are always the same.

I need to have only the values from key2 while maitaining their row. Here is a simple example.

```json
{"primary key1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},
"primary key2":{"key1":"value4","key2":"value5","key3":"value6"}}
```

Comment: is the aforementioned example a single struct row that has 2 fields, or a json represented as a string?

Comment: Its a string in a column, so all entries of the dataframe has one string like the example, some may have 0 or 1 or 10 different primary keys though.